# Invalid field ParentServiceContractId for SObject ServiceContract

Tags: servicecloud, system-fields

I'm getting the error "Invalid field ParentServiceContractId for SObject ServiceContract" when I try to add it to a Visualforce page.

I see the field listed under standard fields and referenced in the documentation. I get the error whether or not it is ParentServiceContractId or ParentServiceContract.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, it's a new field and I was a few API versions behind.

When I updated the version to the current version, it worked.